# QGIS 2.99 projection for unprojected x y- coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I vaguely remember that I have read that QGIS 2.99 has special support for unprojected x-y-coordinates. (In qgis 2.x I used epsg 4326 for this). Where can I find "no-projection" "unprojectes" or something similar in QGIS 2.99?

Comment: in a `project properties>CRS`have `No projection` check

Comment: if you post this as answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `project properties > CRS` have `No projection` check

[image]